# Get first text inside a tag using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-science

I need to get the salary range from span tag. I tried using find().text but doesn't work as the span tag has other tags in it.

```
job_list = soup.find_all("div", class_="d-flex flex-column pl-sm css-1buaf54 job-search-key- 1mn3dn8 e1rrn5ka0")

for job in job_list:
   salary = job.find("span", class_="job-search-key-1hbqxax e1wijj240")
   print(salary)
```

The output I have:

[image]

₹362,870 - ₹955,252 is my desired output

Comment: Please share the URL. or the HTML as _code_, not as an image.

Comment: Hi @tomioka I have written an answer let me know if you have any doubts. If the answer works for you could you please consider accepting it by clicking on check symbol left of the answer box

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to do here is get the text inside the div class but not the text in the nested tags within it.

You can use `soup.find` with option `text = True and recursive = False`

##### Creating the data

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_doc = '''<span class="job-search-key-1hbqxax elwijj240" data-test="detailsalary">
₹362,870 - ₹955,252 <span class="job-search-key- elwijj242">(Glassdoor Est.)</span> <span class="SVGInline greyInfoIcon" data-test="salaryIcon"> <svg class="SVGInline-svg greyInforcon-svg" height="16" viewbox="0 @ 16 16" width="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" id="prefix__info-16-px" stroke="none" stroke-width="1">
<path d="M8 14A6 6 @ 118 2a6 6 @ 010 12zme- 1A5 5 @ 108 3a5 5 @ 880 18zm-.6-5.60.6.6 8 111.2 8v11a.6.6 @ 01-1.2 8v7.42MS 5.62.6.6 110-1.2.6.6 @ 810 1.2z" fill="#505863" id="prefix_a"></path>
</svg> </span>
<div class="d-none"></div> </span>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
```

##### Generating the output

```
soup.find(class_='job-search-key-1hbqxax elwijj240').find(text=True, recursive=False).strip()
```

##### Output

This gives us

```
'₹362,870 - ₹955,252'
```