# How to not return or skip text from a sub element with python and soup or selenium?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a html structure of

```
<div class="price-options ">
      Was $8.50, Save  $4.25
   <br>
   <span class="price">  $4.25 each</span>
   <br>                                             
   <span class="comparative-text">$1.12 per 100g</span>         
</div>
```

How do I get each text element as separate elements?
I thinK I can do find class= price and find class= comparative-text to get 2 separate elements but how do I limit find class=price-options to get only the first bit of text when all the text is rapped in the div class?

I can use something like price_option.find('div','price-options') it will return all the free text because the tree lines of text all are within the div.
If I use comp_text== price_option.find('class','compartive-text) it will find just the $1.12 per 100g

I would like to have 3 returns, 1 for the was..save line, 1 for between the breaks $4.25 each and 1 for the comparative text.
Any for the text elements may be empty.

Should I take the first result and try to break it into 3 or should I try to find the text between the 
 and then remove that and the comparative-text from the original which has all 3.
Not quite sure how I go about slicing and dicing this, using either soup, selenium or something else.
Guidance is appreciated. Samples would be wonderful

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre] that includes *your attempt* along with the desired output?

Comment: I will try. It boils down to how to only get the first bit of text n the <div class="Price-options"> and not the text in the 2 spans. but when performing find('div', class_='price-options'> it returns all the text because it is in the div. Would like to do find('class', 'price-options') and return just Was $8.50, Save  $4.25

Comment: This may be my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72953840/get-first-text-inside-a-tag-using-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 0):

From the link in the comment from an earlier stackoverflow question the answer worked 100% through to the end but threw a deprecation error each time.
The new query I used, wrapped in a try statement to handle None is

product_poption=product_div.find('div',class_='price-options').find(string=True, recursive=False).strip()